# Edit certain lines of textfile - c#

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a text file...

```
HELLO
GOODBYE
FAREWELL
```

.. and two string variables, requested and newname.
I am trying to write a program, that removes 'requested' from the text file and adds 'newname'. However I do not know the concepts and the code to do so. The only concept I can think of is adding all lines to an array then removing 'requested' from the array and adding 'newname' ... but I don't know the code.

I apologies if this is a stupid question, I am new to c#. Help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: have you tried anything at all yet? your idea is not bad, but you should try implementing it before asking for someone to do it for you...

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know the code the fill my concepts.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea should work fine.

Here's a link on how to get the text file contents into a list collection.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/readline

Then you can use List.Add("newname"); and List.Remove("requested");

No stupid questions btw, only stupid ppl to post complaints about it :D

Comment: On the other hand, there is something to be said for finding existing answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044365/adding-a-line-to-the-middle-of-a-file-with-net

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
string path = "file path here";
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
lines.RemoveAll(line => line.Equals(requested));
lines.Add(newname);
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```