# Write in the beginning of a .txt file

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Prepending to beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343044/c-prepending-to-beginning-of-a-file)
>   [Adding a Line to the Middle of a File with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044365/adding-a-line-to-the-middle-of-a-file-with-net)

I have a `file.txt` with text inside and I need to know if is possible to `write`other text in the begining of this file ?

I mean: There's a text and I want to write something else without loosing what I already have inside the `file.txt`. BUT, I want to insert this new text in the begining of the file... Is it possible?

I'm using `StreamWriter` to write inside the file. Just need to know if it's possible and the method to do so.

Comment: Without solutions to my problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: You should read this article :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343044/c-prepending-to-beginning-of-a-file

Comment: Its too easy mark as a duplicated without saying where is the duplicate ,isn't it ? The both links two of you commented here(and now you've erased it) were way different than my problem, you two just needed to read first !

Comment: @Derek thanks, I already read that... Someone marked as duplicate then commmented the same link you just did, then erased the comment, its not duplicated.... Thanks anyway

Comment: -1 for posting you don't understand basic code Ghaleon

Comment: Read again what I commented about your code =) you should get -1 for posting code that has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @Ghaleon I am confused.... the first link _exactly_ answers your question, it even provides you the code needed to accomplish this. Either you are not correctly expressing the problem or you do not understand the code presented?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to place all the text in a string :

```
using System.IO;

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
string initialText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();
```

Then add to the beginning of the string:

```
endText = textAtBeginning & initialText;
```

Then finally write `endText` to replace all text within your file:

```
// Write the string to a file, overwriting the existing text. 

StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt", false))
myWriter.WriteLine(endText);
myWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Got it ! I'll try. I just read the existing file and hold it's text into a `string` then I do the same to the new text then just write it all ?

Comment: Yep. If "New text" is a text file, read it and put it in a string. Then place at the beginning of your string and overwrite the file.

Comment: Edit: I added the code to overwrite the file

Comment: I tried here, then I read the file to the string, its values is all in a single line...

Answer (score 0):

Try this this is best way to do it

File.WriteAllText("debug.txt", "My name is Test");

```
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream("debug.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("whatever you text is"), 0, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("whatever you text is").Length);
        }
```

You must use seek property for writing as the previous example of reading all content and deleting the file and creating new file is not a good practice it's a problem when you have large files so use this is the the best way to do it.
Seek to the position where you want to write and then write it.

Comment: Could you explain it to me please? I dont get it ;s sorry

Comment: Ghaleon, sorry to sound so rude but how can you be a programmer if you can't understand basic coding? do you know how to use the `Debugger?` if so step thru the example ..if not then use `google` to hit `MSDN` and searh `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` `File.Delete` and the `StreamWriter Class`

Comment: @DJKRAZE it was not the code i commented... And your code I already know and its not what I asked,read again... Thanks anyway, and sorry if i've been rude...