# Append XML to file without writing it from scratch?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, file-io

The standard way to append an XML file in LINQ-to-XML is to read it in, modify the in-memory document, and write the whole file out from scratch.  For example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("pathToDoc.xml");
doc.Root.Add(new XElement(namespace + "anotherChild", new XAttribute("child-id", childId)));
doc.Save("pathToDoc.xml");
```

Or, with a `FileStream`:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("pathToDoc.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fs);
    doc.Root.Add(new XElement(namespace + "anotherChild", new XAttribute("child-id", childId)));

    fs.SetLength(0);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs, new UTF8Encoding(false))) {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

However, in both cases, the existing XML document is being loaded into memory, modified in memory, and then written *from scratch* to the XML file.  For small XML files this is OK, but for large files with hundreds or thousands of nodes this seems like a very inefficient process.  Is there any way to make `XDocument` (or perhaps something like an `XmlWriter`) just append the necessary additional nodes to the existing XML document rather than blanking it out and starting from scratch?

Comment: Well formed xml has only one root tag.  So you must read an existing file and add additional tags in the middle of the existing file.

Comment: Yes, but one would hope a good serializer has the intelligence to seek to the right location and append.

Comment: An XML file is just a text file, and there's no easy way to insert in the middle of a text file.  See [Adding a Line to the Middle of a File with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2044365/3744182).  But since you're inserting immediately before the ending tag of the root element, see [Fastest way to add new node to end of an xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849043/3744182) - which might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the position where you need to add the additional elements. Of course you can implement something that removes the closing `"</root>"` tag, writes additional elements and then adds the `"</root>"` again. However, such code is highly optimized for your purpose and you'll probably not find a library for it.

Your code could look like this (quick and dirty, without input checking, assuming that `<root/>` cannot exist):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlAddElementWithoutLoading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var rootelement = "root";
            var doc = GetDocumentWithNewNodes(rootelement);
            var newNodes = GetXmlOfNewNodes(doc);

            using (var fs = new FileStream("pathToDoc.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    RemoveClosingRootNode(fs, rootelement);
                    writer.Write(newNodes);
                    writer.Write("</"+rootelement+">");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveClosingRootNode(FileStream fs, string rootelement)
        {
            fs.SetLength(fs.Length - ("</" + rootelement + ">").Length);
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        }

        private static string GetXmlOfNewNodes(XDocument doc)
        {
            var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader();
            reader.MoveToContent();
            return reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }

        private static XDocument GetDocumentWithNewNodes(string rootelement)
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Parse("<" + rootelement + "/>");
            var childId = "2";
            XNamespace ns = "namespace";
            doc.Root.Add(new XElement(ns + "anotherChild", new XAttribute("child-id", childId)));
            return doc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd have thought it would be relatively common to just want to add elements to the end of parent elements in an XML document?

Comment: @Jez: I added some code for a starting point